# Leave existing HTML entities as-is, but convert double-quotes and single-quotes

Tags: php, html, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

I'm using PHP code to generate my meta description tag, like so:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php
echo $this->utf->clean_string(word_limiter(strip_tags(trim($paperResult['file_content'])),27));
?>
```

Here's an example of the meta description output:

```
<meta name="description" content="blah blah &#182; &#8230; blah blah "words in quotation marks" blah blah "more words in quotation marks" blah blah" />
```

The two HTML entities in that example meta description are a paragraph sign (`&#182;`) followed by an ellipsis (`&#8230;`).  They are already in HTML entity form in the source text, so I want them to remain unchanged.  The problem is that I also need the quotation marks within the description to convert to `&quot;` in order to prevent the meta tag from breaking.  Every combination/configuration that I try either does not work or breaks my site because I'm getting the code wrong.  For example, when I try the following code, the quotation marks convert to their HTML entity, as desired, but the paragraph symbol and ellipsis entities break because the ampersand character at the beginning of the existing HTML entities gets converted to `&amp;`.  That leaves me with a broken `&#182;` (`&amp;#182;`) and a broken `&#8230;` (`&amp;#8230;`) :

```
 echo $this->utf->clean_string(word_limiter(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($paperResult['file_content']))),27));
```

I've been trying—literally, for days—to figure this out.  I've searched extensively in Stack Overflow, to no avail.  I just need the existing HTML entities to remain unchanged and quotation marks to be converted to their HTML entity (`&quot;`).  I have studied the [ENT_QUOTES option](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and I know that the solution probably exists therein, but I can't figure out how to incorporate it into my particular line of code. I'm hoping that you PHP gurus will have mercy on this tortured soul!  I'd truly appreciate your help.

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly does `$paperResult['file_content']` look like?

Comment: Thanks for asking!  It depends on the source file, of which there are over 200,000.  It outputs the first "x" number of words (currently set to 27) at the top of the file.  In many cases. there are both existing HTML entities and quotation marks within those first 27 words.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide some examples

Comment: If it's just the contents of the "content" attribute you can use `echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8", false);` with the last argument (double encode) as false and ENT_QUOTES to convert the quotes.  If it's the whole tag, that's a bit harder.

Comment: Did you see the example that I already provided?  I'm not sure what else to provide.  The output is always 27 words.  The particular words themselves are of no consequence.  Whenever there happens to be a quotation mark (i.e., double quote character) included amongst those 27 words, the meta tag breaks because the quotation mark conflicts with the quotation mark that opens the tag.  Hope that helps.  :)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, you are very likely correct.  I actually tried to use that exact solution, but I just can't seem to correctly incorporate that new code it into my existing line of code without breaking my site.  I dabble in PHP when I have to (as in this situation), but I'm certainly not an expert like you guys.

Comment: When that happens, break the steps apart and then step though each operation one at a time, and check the output.  It could simply be the order in which you are doing things.  An example would be if you strip_tags after using htmlentities, [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b6bc6d32dca341a24d487cf6f146506badd77f40)  Order matters.  I should mention if you have the whole meta tag, then strip tags will remove it (and the content attribute).

Comment: Which brings me to what does it output, if anything?

Comment: You didn't provide any sample input, you only show the output after your many functions had been run on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's the contents of the "content" attribute you can do this

```
$str = 'blah blah &#182; &#8230; blah blah "words in quotation marks" blah blah "more words in quotation marks" blah blah';
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8", false);
```

Output

```
blah blah &#182; &#8230; blah blah &quot;words in quotation marks&quot; blah blah &quot;more words in quotation marks&quot; blah blah
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e231ada7172c47d4c3d0aacab8da9940ffa33404)

The key thing here is the 4th argument

> string htmlentities ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 [, string $encoding = ini_get("default_charset") [, bool $double_encode = TRUE ]]] )

Specifically

> **double_encode**  When double_encode is turned off PHP will not encode existing html entities. The default is to convert everything.

That way it doesn't double encode the ampersand.

`htmlspecialchars` also has a double encode argument.

> htmlspecialchars ( string $string [, int $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401 [, string $encoding = ini_get("default_charset") [, bool $double_encode = TRUE ]]] )

```
$str = 'blah blah &#182; &#8230; blah blah "words in quotation marks" blah blah "more words in quotation marks" blah blah';
echo htmlspecialchars($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8", false);
```

Output

```
blah blah &#182; &#8230; blah blah &quot;words in quotation marks&quot; blah blah &quot;more words in quotation marks&quot; blah blah
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ed2ba628687959a15b90820d581a6b7b183eac93)

If it's the whole tag, then you'll have to pull out the contents and modify it and then replace it so as to preserve the `<` and `>`, but it's not clear in the question if that is the case.

PS there is not a whole lot of difference between `htmlspecialchars` and `htmlentities`, it mainly has to do with `é` accute and other accent things like that, htmlentities encodes those too, if I remember correctly.

**UPDATE**

> I need the solution to be incorporated into my particular format of PHP code (i.e., a single line of PHP that maintains my existing functions/functionality), as miken32 brilliantly did above

To put it in your code,

```
<meta name="description" content="<?=htmlspecialchars(word_limiter(trim($paperResult['file_content']),27),ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8",false);?>"/>
```

**UPDATE2**

With `preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', ' ', $string)`  removes `\r\n` or `\n` one or more times `+`.  But it may be better to do it this way `preg_replace(['/[\r\n]+/', '/\s+/'], ' ', $string)`.  Which would remove run on spaces too.

```
 <meta name="description" content="<?=htmlspecialchars(word_limiter(preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', ' ', trim($paperResult['file_content'])),27),ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8",false);?>"/>
```

Basically what it amounts to is anything that makes the text shorter you probably want to do before `word_limiter` (whatever that is).  And any thing that makes it longer, like changing `"` to `&quote;` you probably want to do after (maybe).  It just seems more logical to me.

Cheers!

Comment: ArtisticPhoenix, I greatly appreciate your time and expertise!  Thank you!  However, in this particular case, I need the solution to be incorporated into my particular format of PHP code (i.e., a single line of PHP that maintains my existing functions/functionality), as miken32 brilliantly did above.  In the perfect world, though, I'd still like to have a solution that leaves all existing HTML entities untouched (i.e., does *not* convert them to the their respective characters) while simultaneously converting quotation marks (i.e., double quotes) to their HTML entity equivalent (`&quot;`).

Comment: It would just be `<meta name="description" content="<?=htmlspecialchars(word_limiter($paperResult['file_content'], 27),ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8", false);?>"/>`

Comment: AWESOME, ArtisticPhoenix!  That works perfectly!  Thank you so much!  One more thing: can you post a second version of your code that incorporates a preg_replace function that replaces 1 or more line breaks with a single space?

Comment: That is kind of a separate question, `preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', ' ', $string)`

Answer (score 1):

I can't be certain since you don't tell us what all those other functions do, but it seems like you could just do this:

```
<meta name="description" content="<?=htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode(word_limiter($paperResult['file_content'], 27)))?>"/>
```

So limit your word count, turn any entities into characters, and then turn any special characters back into entities again. There's no need to be stripping tags and such for security, since `htmlspecialchars` will ensure any output is safe for inclusion in HTML.

Comment: You, sir, rule the world!  You took my existing code structure and made it happen! 

Although my goal was to leave all existing HTML entities untouched while converting each quotation mark to `&quot;`, your solution does the trick!  At least, I _think_ it does.  I hesitate to declare total victory because I am unsure if special characters (like ¶ and …) will appear correctly on Google's SERPs and on all devices.  I have always held the belief that using the HTML entity is more universal and safe.  Any knowledge/opinion on that?

Comment: Everything supports Unicode these days, as long as your server is properly configured, there's little need for entities beyond what `htmlspecialchars()` handles, namely <, >, ", and &. Those being escaped is a requirement for HTML and XML, so can't be avoided.

Comment: If you did want to turn every character to an entity, you can use `htmlentities` in place of `htmlspecialchars`

Comment: I tried that originally, but it broke existing HTML entities by converting each existing entity's beginning ampersand from & to `&amp;`.

Comment: Nope because you’ve got rid of them first with `html_decode_entities`